# nginx - Replace page content on homepage

Tags: string, nginx, replace

I've been having a bit of difficulty setting up nginx on my ubuntu server. Right now its configured to proxy another website. I want to add some content to the main page right after `<body>`. I used:

`subs_filter '<body>' '<body>' My content;`

This works great, the only problem is that it's at every page, How can I use an if statement or something to make it only appear on the homepage. I tried going with

`if ($uri ~ 'index.php')` then do the above filter but that gives an error saying `nginx: [emerg] "subs_filter" directive is not allowed here`.

I looked it up but had a lot of trouble finding what I need :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [*nginx* documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubsModule#subs_filter) `subs_filter` may in used in the `http`, `server` and `location` contexts.

Thus, in order to have the filter activated only for the *index.php* page,

```
location = /index.php {
    subs_filter '<body>' '<body>' My content;
    # other things you would do for index.php
}
```

Comment: Im using it in the location context, the problem is that my root/homepage isnt index.php, its proxied so I dont even know what it is, its just /. But if you use / for location that applies to every page.

Comment: if you use `location = / {` that will match only the `http://domain.com/` page (note the `=`)

Comment: AHH!! I see where what I missed, the `=` Thank you very much.